# Extracting bits one by one from 64 bit integer

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

Any idea how to do this in C++ for uint64_t integers. After some research i found that I need to AND the integer with some mask with that bit set as 1.

so if I want the 50th bit from right should I just and it with 2^50.

Also any Idea how to set a particular bit. I think this will be an expensive operation if I use exponents.

Comment: Any reason you can't just pass your `uint64_t` to a [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) then just use `operator[]` to access any bit you want? Or loop over them or whatever.

Comment: @Cory Overkill and more code to type.

Comment: @zx485 It should be `v >> 49 & 1`.

Comment: @zett42: thx. My comment contained a mistake and so I deleted it.

Comment: @zett42 Well, not so much more code to write https://godbolt.org/z/E8FWPT

Comment: @zx485 can i set the nth bit of value using value|=(1ULL<<n)

Comment: Starting at index n=1 for the first bit, you can set the n-th bit with `value |= (1ULL<<(n-1))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up bit shift operators: `<<`, `>>`. You can do it at least two ways:

- `value&(uint64_t(1)<<50)`: this gives 0 or 2<sup>50</sup>
- `(value>>50)&1`: this gives 0 or 1

Comment: can I use value | (1ULL <<50) to set 50th bit 1

Comment: @pootispencerhere yes

Answer (score 0):

The hardware can do it for decades already, since Intel 386. There’re special instructions for that, `BSF` to find first set bit, `BSR` to find last bit.

If you’re on Windows and using Visual C++, to use these instructions for uint64_t integers, see [_BitScanForward64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/bitscanforward-bitscanforward64?view=vs-2017) and [_BitScanReverse64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/bitscanreverse-bitscanreverse64?view=vs-2017) compiler intrinsics.

Other compilers/platforms are different but they probably expose something similar, Intel 386 is 33 years old now.